# How can I make search and sort logic between different data in MicroServices?

Tags: database, postgresql, nestjs, microservices, typeorm

We have two data tables like item, itemMeta. Each table has CRUD APIs. and each data relations one to one.

```
<item table in A server>
id    name        created_at
------------------------
1     a_text      2022-08-23
2     b_text      2022-08-23
3     c_text      2022-08-23
4     d_text      2022-08-23
5     e_text      2022-08-23
...
xxxx  hello_text  2022-08-23
...

<itemMeta table in B server>
id    itemId  price   created_at
--------------------------------
1     1       10      2022-08-23
1     11      110      2022-08-23
1     24      420      2022-08-23
1     4       130      2022-08-23
1     5       1340      2022-08-23
....
yyyy  xxxx    500     2022-08-23
....
```

When I want make endpoint like

> /search-with-item-meta?search=o_text&page=4&sort=highprice-to-lowprice

I shoud call items with search text and call itemMeta with price sort infomations and then matching two datas with uniq id.

but item table hasn't price and itemMeta table hasn't title and also has pagination. Unfortunately, two table is different DB and seperate place. so It should call with APIs.

simply I will make complete with add field price at item, add field title at itemMeta. But It is not clear. and worried about to sync with two table and pagination.

How can I solve this issues?

We used Postgresql DB with typeorm and NestJS

Answer (score 0):

I am writing this answer based on MySql.

Ensure that you have made the relationship between the entities then Create a `queryBuilder` and join the two tables in your `items` repository like below

```
relationalQuery(){
    return itemRepository.createQueryBuilder("items")
           .leftJoinAndSelect("items.itemMeta","itemMeta")
}
```

Now we need a function to pass all parameter to filter them and return paginated response

```
async findAll(page: number, limit: number, search: string, sort: string, _queryBuilder: SelectQueryBuilder<T>){

    queryBuilder = _queryBuilder.take(limit).skip((page - 1) * limit)
    if (sort) {
        let order = "ASC"
        if (sort === "highprice-to-lowprice") {
            order = "DESC"
        }
        queryBuilder.addOrderBy("itemMeta.price", order)
    }
    if (search) {
        queryBuilder.andWhere(new Brackets((qb: SelectQueryBuilder<T>) => {
            condition = {
                operator: like,
                parameters: [`${qb.alias}_name}`, `:${name}`],
            }
            qb = qb.orWhere(qb['createWhereConditionExpression'](condition), {
                name: `%${search}%`
            }),
            })
        })


    [items, totalItems] = await queryBuilder.getManyAndCount()

    let totalPages = totalItems / limit
    if (totalItems % limit) totalPages = Math.ceil(totalPages)
    retrun{
        items,
        totalItems,
        totalPages,
    }
}
```

Calling this function

```
const query = relationalQuery()
findAll(1,15,"o_text","highprice-to-lowprice",query)
```

This is a demo of how to implement it. You can add a column-wise filter, sort and search.Then you have to pass a object for sort like

```
sort_by:{
   name:"ASC",
   id: "DESC",
   "itemMeta.price":"DESC"
}
```

You have to make a customize pagination function like the above where you have to break down all the columns and operations of your own.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but It is not my case.
item table and itemMeta table should not using <join> because they are different server.

Comment: Data would be able to get using only API call on each server.